# WillCascadeOnDelete without base entity knowing of foreign entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity in my core application:

```
public class Contact : BaseEntity
{
    //Some properties
}
```

I then have an entity in a plugin (not part of the main DLL) like so:

```
public class AdditionalContactData
{
    public string SomePropertyThatIsntOnTheMainContact { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact { get; set;}
}
```

After binding the models etc via EF, this creates the tables with the foreign keys as I would expect. The issue I have is that I want to be able to delete a `Contact` entity and it cascade down to remove `AdditionalContactData`. This wouldn't be an issue if `Contact` could know about `AdditionalContactData` i.e:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Contact)
    .WithOptional(m => m.AdditionalContactData)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

This would work (and would be what I'd do in normal circumstances)

How can I achieve the same thing BUT **without** `Contact` knowing about `AdditionalContactData`. Is this possible?

I'm hoping I've been clear enough but please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that this is code from `AdditionalContactData` configuration, just remove optional property expression from `WithOptional`:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Contact)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: I accepted this initially as it fixed the issue however upon more testing being done, it stops the `Contact_Id` column being added to the `AdditionalContactData` table? Do you know why this is the case? I still need to be able to reference the contact from the additionalcontact.

Comment: The thing you're trying to do, is a 1-0..1 relation, where left side is `Contact`, and right side is `AdditionalContactData`. From the point of database, primary key of a table, which corresponds to `AdditionalContactData` is also a foreign key to a PK field of `Contact` table. From the point of EDM, you can add `Contact` *navigation property* to `AdditionalContactData` class, but you can't add *foreign key* property like `ContactId`, because primary key property of `AdditionalContactData` **is** a foreign key property for `Contact` by definition.

Comment: Ok, so I assume I have to pick one or the other in that case then?

Comment: Yes. Consider PK of `AdditionalContactData` just like any other foreign key property. Another option you could use here, is a Table-Per-Type inheritance (you can inherit `AdditionalContactData` from `Contact`), but it also has some specific.

Comment: Thanks for your time Dennis. I'll have a play around and see if TPT will help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an unidirectional relationship:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Contact)
.WithOptional()
.WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s06.html) for more info about this.

Comment: Could you take a look at the comment for the other answer please and let me know your thoughts?